# $R=(3+\sqrt 5)^{2n}$ and $f=R-[R]$, where $[.]$ is an integer part function. Then find $R(1-f)$

Tags: binomial-theorem

$f$ basically stands for the fractional part of $R$, but since value of $n$ isnt know, I don’t understand how it’s possible to derive it, because it is tricky to write in general terms. How do I solve it?

Comment: Think about $${(3+\sqrt{5})}^{2n}+{(3-\sqrt{5})}^{2n}$$ and the fact that $3-\sqrt{5}<1$

Comment: I think it is $4^{2n}$

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I did that, but now I am stuck with the sum $2(\binom n0 3^n + \binom n1 3^{n-2}(5)....$ I don’t know how to add

Comment: @Aditya  Note that $(1-f) = (3-\sqrt{5})^{2n}$

Comment: @Forester can you elaborate?

Comment: @Aditya I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding it as an answer because it was way too clumsy for a comment.

Let $(3+\sqrt{5})^{2n} + (3 - \sqrt{5})^{2n} = I$ where $I$ is an integer

$[(3+\sqrt{5})^{2n}] = I-1$(because $(3-\sqrt{5})^{2n}$ is a small fraction)

$f = (3 + \sqrt{5})^{2n} - [(3 + \sqrt{5})^{2n}] = (3+\sqrt{5})^{2n}-I+1=(3+\sqrt{5})^{2n}-(3+\sqrt{5})^{2n} - (3 - \sqrt{5})^{2n}+1$

$f=-(3 - \sqrt{5})^{2n}+1$

$1-f = (3-\sqrt{5})^{2n}$